# They or these. What should I use here?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

My I asked my friend:

> Did you hear 'xyz' song

He said:

> No, such things piss me off

I replied:

> But **they/these** get me high!

What should I reply, ***they*** or ***these***?

Comment: Please check the grammar in your question.

Comment: From what I have understand if it is a single song then "It" should be used if it is many songs they or these can be used

Comment: *These* doesn't really make sense to me.  *These* is used to refer to things that are present, but nothing is present in your example.

Comment: So what else should I've used?

Comment: *They* sounds much more natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use "it" if you mean the song gets you high. Use "they" if you mean the band gets you high (even in AmE). Use "he" or "she" if you mean the singer gets you high.

Use "these" if you have several things (maybe pills or "special" cigarettes) in front of you that could get you high.

Note that in America at least, "getting high" nowadays almost always refers to a state of euphoria achieved through use of drugs. In the past (decades ago) it might have been used to refer to the effects of alcohol. I can also be used to refer to a state of euphoria achieved by other means (as in "get high on life") but this will be understood to refer to a state similar to what you'd get by using drugs.

If you don't mean to say this music puts you in a similar state as using drugs, you should think of an alternate way to say this, such as, "this song makes me feel great" or "this song gives me a beautiful feeling".

Comment: also in British English